# В чем разница между "Аллегория" и "Аналогия"?

Tags: значение-слов

Где уместно использовать `Аллегорию`, а где `Аналогию`?

Википедия мало что мне дала.

Все что я понял, `Аллегорию` используют в основном в литературе, а `Аналогию` намного шире: математика, физика, философия право.

Хотелось бы пример который приемлем только для `Аналогии` и отдельный для `Аллегории`. Что чаще используют в речи?

Спасибо.

Comment: А что из того малого дала? Ну, чтоб не повторяться.

Comment: @shampar Все что я понял, `Аллегорию` используют в основном в литературе. А аналогия намного шире: математика, физика, философия право. Хотелось бы пример который приемлем только для `Аналогии` и отдельный для `Аллегории`. Что чаще используют в речи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Аллегория (иносказание) – художественный прием, изображающий (словом, маслом, глиной)  реально существующие объекты, но символизирующие собой  стихию потусторонних сил или образы, недоступные непосредственному наблюдению. https://www.liveinternet.ru/users/4845230/post360914706/
Аллегориями насыщены библейские сюжеты в изобразительном искусстве.

Аналогия – соответствие и соразмерность,  результат логического  анализа при сравнении, сопоставлении. Аналогия - метод познания окружающего реального мира и человеком обыкновенным и современной наукой.

Пример аллегории:
ЮСТИЦИЯ (IVSTITIA), Аллегория Правосудия. П.Баратта. Италия. Нач. XVIII в. Персонификация правосудия. http://spbfoto.spb.ru/foto/details.php?image_id=698
Богиня правосудия, вторая жена Юпитера (Зевса).
Меч в руках Юстиции (Фемиды) - символ возмездия. Он обоюдоострый, поскольку закон не только карает, но и предупреждает. Меч опущенный острием вниз символизирует победу воина над противником.
Весы Фемиды https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0 – символ (аллегория)  правосудия.

Пример аналогии:
Закон — что дышло: куда повернёшь — туда и вышло.
В этой словесной формуле, как и в любой математической, нет отсылки к потусторонним силам (нет никаких аллегорий). Дышло символизирует самое себя и жизненный опыт.

Аллегория нисколько не устарела, для нее есть место и в наши дни. Достаточно вспомнить стихотворение Р. Гамзатова «Журавли»:
«Летит, летит по небу клин усталый —
Летит в тумане на исходе дня,
И в том строю есть промежуток малый —
Быть может, это место для меня!»

или взглянуть на эту скульптуру  - http://old.rzhev.histrf.ru/static/images/tild6637-3030-4162-b633-663532653638__194145-0.jpg